# How to choose wire gauge for 30 0 30 6A secondary transformer winding

Tags: transformer

I want design transformer of 250 watt I have EI core bobbin size 4.5cm*3.8cm how to select secondary wire gauge if i want 30 0 30 6A on output of transformer.can consider gauge for 6A or 3A.If I consider 6A  60v*6A=360W or 30V*6A=180w. please help.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Core selection**

Core area for standard core (steel laminations) is equal to the square root of the power.

[image]

Thus for a 360VA transformer you need a "tongue" core area of 19 sq.cm (at least), with permeability of about 500. With the core you have, you can have a maximum power of 290VA (losses included).

[image]

In a well designed transformer, the core window will be almost completely.

**2. Number of turns**

It is calculated as turns/volt and it is the same for primary and secondary. One of main parameters is the line frequency. For 50Hz transformer is

[image]

for 60Hz, turns are fewer and replace 45 with 38/core area. Core with higher flux densities give the possibility for fewer turns/volt.

**3. Wire gauge**

Current density is the key factor for the current output capability of the transformer within a safe temperature i.e around 50 C. A 2.565A/mm² it is a good choice. Higher densities results in temperature increase but lower increase the weight of transformer and may be you need to use next size of core in order to wound your wire.

Here you can use the position of the primary and secondary. For example for secondary which is in outer of the transformer you can use a current density of 4.8A/ mm², but for primary which is not cooling enough use  a lower current density i.e 2.1A/ mm².

So in 230v/50Hz environment and with the available core you can construct transformer with 30-0-30 at total 4.2A (60v/4.2A) using 647 turns with AWG 18 magnet wire for primary, and 168 turns (with center tap) using AWG 15 for secondary.

Answer (score 0):

Can refer the below table its from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge)
[image]

Comment: I am confuse how to select gauge of wire can I assume 6A for 60v or 6A for 30 V because watt difference too much I want CT transformer.

Comment: Here one should look for the power carrying through the wire and that can be calculated using formula. p(t)=u(t)⋅i(t).

But the voltage here is not the supply voltage, but the voltage drop across the wire, which is determined by the current passed through it. p(t)=R⋅i2(t). R is constant, so it really depends only on the current.

In typical setting, the resistance of the wire will be negligible compared to resistance of the load, so the current running through it will be determined solely by the load resistance (or impedance in general).